# Android get Unexpected response code 500 with Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

i have simple link as `GET` to retrieve data from server which thats implemented on windows server and my android application must can get data from that, response is `json` format, for example when i use this link on `FireFox` address bar :

```
http://MY_SITE/android/main.aspx?page=1&cat=0
```

i get `JsonArray` response as :

```
[{"ID":27,"Number":"03331514800","Price":1500000,"Date":"","Status":0,"Cat":"$1$4$8$8$9$23$","SalesName":null,"TransID":null,"SalesDate":null,"SalesTime":null,"SalesSuccess":false}]
```

its correct but i get this error `Unexpected response code 500` when i use `Volley` library

my code:

```
private void getLatestSimCardNumbers() {
    fetch_server_url = Application.getHostAddress() + "http://MY_SITE/android/main.aspx";

    HashMap<String, String> jsonBody = new HashMap<>();

    jsonBody.put("page", "1");
    jsonBody.put("cat", "0");

    HttpsTrustManager.allowAllSSL();
    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(fetch_server_url, new JSONObject(jsonBody),
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.e("RESPONSE", response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("ERR ", "");
        }
    });
    int         socketTimeout = 30000;
    RetryPolicy policy        = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    req.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    Application.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

Comment: Your URL is not working in browser so i think its having problem in server side.

Comment: @MayurPatel my url work fine on firefox without any problem sir,

Comment: it not working in firefox and chrome. it check that and you read this article Link : https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html

Comment: @MayurPatel when i get result after paste on firefox address bar and send request, i get response as JSON format which i pasted that on my post, you think its have problem?

Comment: 500 means error from server end. Debug in internal classes of Volley to get exact error

Comment: I think change your URL fetch_server_url = "http://MY_SITE/android/main.aspx";
and let me know that is inside Application.getHostAddress()?

Comment: 500 means your internal server error .... u need to do debugging.